# Get sum of value in sqlite table and display in text widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite

I am creating a app in flutter and sqlite.i have a table named leave_details. I want to get total number of leave by yearly and category wise and show inside text widget.
as example 2023 casual leaves = 3,sick leaves = 6,2022 sick leaves = 4

```
        Center(
            child: Column(
              children: snapshot.data!.map((leave) {
                return Table(
                  columnWidths: {
                    0: FractionColumnWidth(0.44),
                    1: FractionColumnWidth(0.25),
                  },
                  children: [
                    TableRow(children: [
                      Text(
                        'Casual Leaves in 2023 ',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '03',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(children: [
                      Text(
                        'Sick Leaves in 2023 ',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '06',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ],
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
```

[image: leave_detail table]

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the relevant values using:-

```
SELECT sum(num_leave_days), leave_year, leave_category FROM leave GROUP BY leave_year,leave_category;
```

- Assuming that the table name is **leave**

**However** id 2023/02/05 really 4 days, is the 4 a typo or are the dates the typo (rhetorical).

In short there is no need for the num_leave_days column as this can easily (except for the date format) be derived from the start and end.

An issue is then that SQLite Date/Time functions do not recognise YYYY/MM/DD as a format. Instead they do recognise YYYY-MM-DD. However, this can be converted by **`replace`** the `/` with `-` and the date difference can be ascertained with reference to the potential typo (e.g. 4 instead of 2).

As such the query could be

```
SELECT sum(
    (
        strftime(
            '%s', /* use the number of secdonds since 1/1/1970 aka UTC */
            replace(leave_end_date,'/','-') /* The date in yyyy-mm-dd format */
        )
        
        - /* MINUS */
        
        strftime(
            '%s',
            replace(leave_start_date,'/','-')
        )
    ) 
    / (60 * 60 * 24) /* Strip of the house, minutes and seconds i.e. just the days */
)
    , leave_year, leave_category /* Other useful columns */
FROM leave 
GROUP BY leave_year,leave_category;
```

- expanded to make it easier to what is what.

Comment: how to show sum(num_leave_days) inside text widget in flutter